# add created record in table after back to first screen

Tags: sapui5

i have two screen ..firstview contains table...in second view am successfully creating a new record ...after navigating to first screen new record should add to table...here table is not showing the created new record.

```
    if i reload app then its showing...but it has to show on navigating back..

    firstview.xml

    <Table  items="{path:'/Emp'}" id="table_id">    

    firstcontroller

//    url="/Emp"
    //  var table = this.byId("table_id");
   //               table.bindItems({
    //                  path: url,
    //                  template: table.getBindingInfo("items").template});




    second controller

    creat: function(oEvent) {
    creating a new record by calling odata.......

    model.create()


    },

    //if i go back to first screen then new created record should add to table in first view..how to refres table on back from second view to first view
        onNavBack : function() {


                    this.getRouter().navTo("firstcontroller", {}, true);
                },
```

Comment: The answer to this would depend on where you have the binding code. If you have written in onInit method of controller, then rebinding will not not take place. Similarly creation should be followed by a read. Generally UI5 framework will be handle this but need to check specifics here. The better way is to ensure the binding is refreshed in routeMatched handler in the first view. So that the control returns from View the binding is refreshed to load the new data.

Comment: not binded in onInit ...i have done binding in xml ..how to refresh from xml binded

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I think you're not refreshing the model once it has been updated. Try refreshing your model.

Try to refresh in the function where you're going back.

If you didn't get after that also means. Please share the code where you're adding new record and code where you're going back.

You can refresh table model by below code:

```
this.getView().byId("table_id").getModel().refresh();
```